# Application is not visible in Azure

Tags: azure, flask, web-applications

I built a webpage from Flask for learning purpose using github. It was deployed without any issue. But when ever I opens up the page, following page gets opened.

[image]

Following is the log summary.

```
3:11:35 PM
Updating submodules.
3:11:36 PM
Preparing deployment for commit id 'd5d6a931-d'.
3:11:36 PM
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
3:11:36 PM
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
3:11:36 PM
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
3:11:36 PM
Running oryx build...
Show Logs...
3:13:44 PM
Running post deployment command(s)...
3:13:44 PM
3:13:44 PM
Generating summary of Oryx build
3:13:44 PM
Parsing the build logs
3:13:44 PM
Found 0 issue(s)
3:13:45 PM
3:13:45 PM
Build Summary :
3:13:45 PM
===============
3:13:45 PM
Errors (0)
3:13:45 PM
Warnings (0)
3:13:45 PM
3:13:45 PM
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
3:13:46 PM
Deployment successful. deployer = GITHUB_ZIP_DEPLOY deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
```

This is  the first time I'm using this. Can you give me a hint why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the application is not deployed properly.

- Check the logs if the app is deployed to Azure.

[image]

---

I have taken flask web app code from [github repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-flask-webapp-quickstart) given by *vmagelo* and deployed to Azure App Service through Github Actions.

**Local Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Github:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

After deploying to Azure, I was facing the same issue as you mentioned that unable to trigger the application.

[image]

**Configuration:**

[image]

**FIX:**

***I have added the below configurations in App Service-> Settings->Configuration*** and restarted the App Service, it worked without any issues.
`WEBSITES_PORT:<port_number_which_your application_listening_to>`

[image]

**Portal Output:**
[image]